# Auto-Tweet if Type is 'Status' using OAuth

Tags: functions, actions, twitter

Should be simple - I'd like WP to tweet the content of a post once (when it's published the first time) if the post format is 'status'.

The code below isn't returning an error on publish, nor is it tweeting OR updating the post metadata, which leads me to believe I'm either using the hook incorrectly or there's something wrong with checking the post type as I have.

This is currently living in my functions.php

I'm using Matt Harris' [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) and have successfully tweeted from a standalone tweet.php using most of the function below.

Keys and secrets removed for security.

```
function posse_twitter( $post ) {
    // check post type if necessary
    if ( $post->post_type != 'status' ) return;

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $tweet_content = $post->post_content;

    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', $single = true ) ) {
        // ...run code once
        //Include Libraries
        require 'libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php';
        require 'libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhUtilities.php';
        $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
          'consumer_key'    => 'XXXXX',
          'consumer_secret' => 'XXXXX',
          'user_token'      => 'XXXXX',
          'user_secret'     => 'XXXXX',
        ));

        $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/update'), array(
          'status' => $tweet_content
        ));

        if ($code == 200) {
          tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
        } else {
          tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', true );
    }
}

add_action( 'draft_to_published', 'posse_twitter' );
```

Comment: Have you already checked the contents of the vars? How long do you get something? Is `$tweet_content/$post->post_content` set? If so: Delete the meta value (or update to `false` as long as you're developing, so you can test it).

Comment: @kaiser what's the best way to check for contents where I'm using them? i.e. since the function runs on publish? (I would just echo, but I'm not sure where/when that will get spit out.)

Comment: `var_dump( $post->post_content );` inside... or have I understood you wrong? Seems like a funny question for someone writing such advanced code, so I guess I'm missing the point of your question.

Comment: @kaiser dumping the contents of the post won't do much in this context, the results of the action aren't visible to the user.

Comment: @kaiser I did var_dump into the error log once the function was executing. Dumping the `$post` object gives me `int(730)`, which is the correct post ID. Dumping anything from the object (e.g. `$post->post_type`) returns NULL.

Comment: Then you'll have to call `get_post( $post );` to get the full object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post` isn't available during `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`, but `$post_ID` is. We pass that to the function and then call in `$post` globally.

I should have also been testing using `get_post_format()`, not for a type.

After those corrections, everything seems to be running smoothly with the caveat that if the post is not auto-saved or saved as a draft prior to hitting publish, things like `$post->post_content` will still be empty during `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`.

New code below.

```
function posse_twitter( $post_ID ) {
    global $post;
    // check post type if necessary
    if ( get_post_format( $post->ID ) != 'status' ) return;

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $tweet_content = $post->post_content;

    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', $single = true ) ) {
        // ...run code once
        require 'libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php';
        require 'libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhUtilities.php';
        $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
          'consumer_key'    => 'XXXX',
          'consumer_secret' => 'XXXX',
          'user_token'      => 'XXXX',
          'user_secret'     => 'XXXX',
        ));

        $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/update'), array(
          'status' => $tweet_content
        ));

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', true );
    }
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'posse_twitter' );
```

Handy: [Adam Brown's API reference](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you aren't hitting the `{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}` action, which is what you are hooking to with `draft_to_published` - for new posts there is no guarantee that the "old" status is actually "draft". Have you tried using the `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` action, which in your case would be `publish_status`?

Comment: Can I get an example of what variable hook implementation looks like? It's not `add_action( {$new_status}_{$post->post_type}, 'posse_twitter' );` is it?

Comment: no, it would be `add_action('publish_status', 'posse_twitter' );` - "publish" is your new status, and "status" is your post type.

Comment: For debugging purposes you could add an `error_log('executing posse_twitter()')` at the very top of your function and then check your php error log to make sure it is getting called.

Comment: `publish_status` wasn't working; tried a standard `publish_post`. Finally got the function to execute (logged), but nothin else so far.

Comment: @EdburyEnegren what version of WP are you on? Can you update with your latest code?

Comment: Latest beta. Answered my own question after a night of hair-pulling - was testing for type instead of format, which is what my aim was. Idiot moment.